How to Solve Infinite Continued Fraction: [2; -2, -2 ...] (the -2's repeat)
I was wondering if someone could help show me how to solve the infinite continued fraction:
$2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2- ...}}}}$
Attempting to solve via calculator gave a value that seemed to approach 1, however I was wondering if someone could show me how to prove that result (or disprove it).
In my attempts to solve it by hand I was following the idea of doing:
$x= -\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2- ...}}}}$
And following the strategy of:
$x= -\frac{1}{2+x} = -\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2+x}}$ (and so on)
However, I quickly proved this to be ineffective for this question (or at least my understanding was subpar).
I was wondering if someone could help, firstly show me how to solve this problem, but then also similar problems.
Thank you!!
also other than continued fractions I am unsure what tags to add if someone could tell me I would be grateful

Let $y= 2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2- ...}}}}$  Then you get $y=2-\frac 1y$ which gives $y^2-2y+1=0$ and you can solve the quadratic.  One of the roots is what you want.

How do we decide when we can use such a substitution for infinite sums? For example, if I have $1-1+1-1...$ then, I can't change it to $sum=1-sum$, but it seems okay to do that with this case of continued fractions. I am trying to understand why? My guess is that we can do it here because the sum is well defined, but $1-1+1...$ is undefined, but how do we prove that?

@Shraiysh Good question.  Actually, the equation $~y = 2 - \dfrac{1}{y}~$ is valid if and only if the expression converges to a value.  So, a preliminary step is to prove that the expression is convergent.  I suspect that there is no easy approach here, and that you actually have to study continued fractions in order to be able to prove convergence. ...see next comment

@Shraiysh If you are interested in the literature, you might consider chapter 1 only (at least to start) of this pdf and this entire pdf.

Also note that proving convergence is often easier if we have a candidate for the limit. So assuming convergence and finding the limit before actually proving convergence is often easier than doing it the other way around.

Would it be possible, given that our answer ended in a quadratic to have continuous fractions which produce two solutions?

I don't think so.  I believe you can prove that every continued fraction converges to a limit because as you go further in to the fraction each successive number has less influence on the value.
